# SimpleDateFormat within an Oracle 11.2 java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, simpledateformat

I have a date parsed within a java stored procedure.
I am parsing it with a SimpleDateFormat, but it is not working.
I have reduced the issue and hardcoded the date value and the format, but I am still getting the error!

```
String date;
try
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    date = sdf.parse("20130606174509").toString();
}
catch (Exception e2)
{
    date = e2.getMessage();
}
```

The error (The String date) is :

```
Unparseable date: "20130606174509"
```

Obviously the same code is ok outside Oracle.

Any idea ?

Comment: The code you have listed works fine.

Comment: Is it possible that this parsing depends on the locale? For example, 17:45 might not be parsable for countries which use AM/PM. I tried with different locales but could not reproduce the problem. Can you tell me what's the locale on your server?

Comment: FYI - AM/PM shouldn't be an issue - the `H` format char means military hours (0-23).  If you want AM/PM hours you use the `K` format char for the hours, and `a` for the AM/PM marker.

Comment: Yes the Locale should not be an issue there as the format is simple.
Using the jre provided with Oracle database the execution is ok. As the execution is inside Oracle, I cannot debug this issue... And I cannot add traces as the code is inside jre classes... Maybe I forgot to add some calls to dbms_java.grant_permission ?

Comment: 1/ I downloaded a jdk 1.5.0_17, same version as the one provided with Oracle installation.
2/ I copied the source of SimpleDateFormat and few others classes from the jdk to my java project.
3/ I uploaded everything to Oracle.
4/ Using the uploaded SimpleDateFormat, the parsing is ok...

My intention was to have a customizable SimpleDateFormat in order to add logs to trace the issue, but the issue is not reproduced! What the hell is going on?

Comment: I tried to debug the code using jpda and managed to set break points in my code. But break points set in the source of SimpleDateFormat from jdk 1.5.0_17 are not corresponding. And step into seems buggy. Anyway it seems that SimpleDateFormat inside my Oracle database does not correspond to the SimpleDateFormat of the downloaded 1.5.0_17 jdk...

Comment: Very funny. I removed C:\Softwares\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar which, I suppose, should contain SimpleDateFormat and many important java classes. I restarted the server. And java is still working. And I have still the same error message... Is Oracle using a different jre? How could it happen?

Comment: The explanation of the above comment is that oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk is not used for java stored procedure but for some gui tools. Consequently I don't know how I could debug SimpleDateFormat of the database I have not got either the source or the binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution used: Oracle re-installation.
No explanation found.